# Adobe CQ - CQ5 - Limit a component to only being usable on a given page template

Tags: aem, custom-component

I am developing components for **CQ5** and wish to control them so that `component A` is only displayed in the sidekick if the page is of `template T_A`, and `components B` and `C` are only visible if the page is of type `template T_B`, however I have so far not been able to find a set of properties to allow this.

Does anyone know of any way to achieve this functionality?

---

I am also able to retrieve the page template in code via the use of
`currentPage.getProperties().get("cq:template", "").equals(MyTemplate)`  however, once I have not been able to find a way to control sidekick component visibility.

I have also attempted variation on [Disabling The Components Tab](http://experience-aem.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/get-sidekick-instance-and-disable.html), however this too has met with no success (even at the level of disabling the entire components tab).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict the components in AEM 5.6.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275062/restrict-the-components-in-aem-5-6-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is baked into CQ5 and requires no special coding. The general way of controlling what components are visible in the side kick (specially what components are allowed for a given parsys) is controlled via a design. The remainder of my answer is based on the assumption that you have no special requirement other than controlling what components are allowed for a parsys (i.e no run time requirements).

The components (or component groups) allowed for a parsys are stored in the design of the site . You can control this behavior by editing the design dialog of the parsys.

The steps for achieving this are as follows

- Go to design mode by clicking on the ruler icon at the bottom of the side kick
- Click on edit button of the required parsys
- Check the components required from the allowed component list

The allowed components are stored on per template basis. Since this data is stored in a design , all the pages must have the same design. The design must be exported too, for this to work across instances [ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049259/limiting-allowed-components-in-a-template-in-cq5
]

Comment: Not entirely what I had in mind but it suffices and does the job, hence accepted as the answer.  Cheers:)