# Questions on the answer for "Limiting allowed components in a template in cq5"

Tags: aem

I saw an answer by Alisneaky from this link:
[Limiting allowed components in a template in cq5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049259/limiting-allowed-components-in-a-template-in-cq5/24692001#24692001)
But I have a question on the answer provided by Alisneaky who suggested to put the following in the template:

```
   <TEMPLATENAME jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
       <content
           jcr:lastModified="{Date}2014-04-11T13:04:48.855+10:00"
           jcr:lastModifiedBy="admin"
           jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
           sling:resourceType="/libs/foundation/components/parsys"
           components="[/libs/foundation/components/text,
                        /libs/foundation/components/textimage]">
       </content>
   </TEMPLATENAME>
```

I tried to put these in the .content.xml under the /etc/designs/mysite and didn't see any components displayed in the sidekick. However, if I open the design dialog, I do see the checkbox checked along with these predefined components.

I also put these lines in my template, this time, I didn't see anything in both sidekick and design dialog.

My questions:
1. where to put these lines? in my template or in the .content.xml under the /etc/designs/mysite

2. Anything I have to configure in order for these predefined components list displayed in the sidekick? (I did point the designPath to /etc/designs/mysite in the page property).

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this configuration under .content.xml of your design. So if you have to following project structure:

```
├── jcr_root
    ├── apps
    │   └── company
    │       └── project
    │           ├── components
    │           │   ├── component1
    │           │   └── component2
    │           │   └── component3
    │           ├── pages
    │           │   └── mypage
    │           └── templates
    │               └── mypage
    └── etc
        └── designs
            └── company
                └── project
```

Say, your page template looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Template"
    jcr:title="My page template title"
    jcr:description="My page template description"
    allowedPaths="[/content(/.*)?]">
    <jcr:content
        jcr:primaryType="cq:PageContent"
        sling:resourceType="company/project/pages/mypage"
        cq:designPath="/etc/designs/company/project">
        <content
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"/>   
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

Than you can put in your .content xml under /etc/designs/company/project/.content.xml the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Page">
    <jcr:content
        cq:doctype="HTML_5"
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        jcr:title="My website design"
        sling:resourceType="wcm/core/components/designer">
        <mypage jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <content
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="foundation/components/parsys"
                components="[/apps/company/project/components/component1,/apps/company/project/components/component2]">
                <section jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
            </content>
        </mypage>
    </jcr:content>
</jcr:root>
```

This way you allow the components company/project/components/component1 and company/project/components/component2 (same for foundation components as your example) to be dropped inside the content node with type of foundation/components/parsys.
But I suggest that you always make the changes through the designer in [design mode](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/working_with_cq_wcm.html#Sidekick) and export the generated .content.xml with the package manager. This way has been proved to be the safest way to perform changes on your design. Even if your changes in the xml are valid and deploy them to cq, sometimes cq refuses to apply these settings (exactly your case, the settings are shown in the sidekick, but are not actually applied).

So the answer of your first question is, you have to put these settings inside your design. About your second question, no you don't have to configure anything else except of the right design path with your template.