# Restricting a Component to a specific template in AEM6.1

Tags: aem

I have a requirement where I have to restrict some components to a specific template like Home Page Template. After that those component should not appear in any other template pages.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict components within a template per-se. 
What you can do is restrict components within the Renderer Component that is related to the template - referenced in template as `sling:resourceType`
You would do that in the design section located in `/etc/designs/defaults` or `/etc/designs/{yourApp}` depending on how your designs are configured.

To get to know how it works

- go to your page
- change view to DESIGN mode
- Alter some parsys properties and save them
- go to /etc/designs to see what has changed and how.

afterwards the `/etc/designs/{yourApp}` should be exported back to your repository to be able to transfer across environments.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to restrict components to be available in certain templates either by

1. Setting the components in the design config of your template. Designs are stored in /etc/designs/ and each template should use a design as a best practice though it is possible to create templates without design.

or

2. The other option is to specify the list of components allowed in the template in the template '.content.xml' file. Please see [Limiting allowed components in a template in cq5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049259/limiting-allowed-components-in-a-template-in-cq5) for details.