# How to restrict components on template level in AEM

Tags: aem

Is there any way to restrict the components on template level. 
For example i have three templates :-
template_1,template_2,template_3 .
There are 5 components.
comp_1,comp_2,comp_3,comp_4,comp_5.

Now in template_1 i want to display comp_1,comp_2,comp_3. where as in template_2 & template_3 i want to show only comp_4,comp_5.

I have try to achieve this by adding multi string property name 'component' on template as suggested on below link :-
[Limiting allowed components in a template in cq5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049259/limiting-allowed-components-in-a-template-in-cq5)

But not able to achieve this. Can anyone help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up custom design files which are restricting the usage of  components on templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
> I have try to achieve this by adding multi string property name
> 'component' on template as suggested on below link :- Limiting allowed
> components in a template in cq5
```

Are you sure you tried "components". This should actually work for you. I see in your question you have added a property 'component' instead of 'components'